# Wide blog theme for drupal

Tags: theming

I've been searching internet for paid or free drupal themes that is best for blogs and does have wide space for html context, not center of screen with a very tight space.

Tight space example:
http://envato.tabvn.com/demo.php?theme=aqua
responsive-blog for drupal

As you can see, they are simply wasting whole html area space and using only middle of it.

In fact, I want something like this:
http://fumalwareanalysis.blogspot.com/p/malware-analysis-tutorials-reverse.html

I'm currently using free Best Responsive. Also it should work properly in mobile devices and ipad, so if browser is mobile device, resize it or fit the page etc.
Any good example theme for drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify Best Responsive theme enlarging the page width. More precisely changing #wrap ID width from 960px to something bigger, like 1200px or a percentual value like 90%.

You can edit the style.css file and change the width from:

```
#wrap {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to:

```
#wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You'll have to update some other elements width like #content and #sidebar using a percentual value and fix the sidebar background image.

Anyway the theme can easily be customized.

In this way the template is still responsive but on desktop the size is more wide.

I hope this will help.

Regards.